# Customizing Accordion Based On Product Selected

Tags: shopify, accordion

So I am wondering how I can change the image under an accordion section for just one product page and not the others. I see in the code of the product page template where the image is located but I am not experienced enough to know how to change it for just the one product. Is there a way to do this without needing to create a whole new template?

Website: https://auntethels.com (I'm trying to change the image under "heating instructions" for just the Lentil Chili Pot Pie product page)

Not sure if it helps but here is the code snippet I found: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luiho.png)

(I need the 'directions.png' to be different for just the one page.)

I've been able to make other changes she needed but this one has stumped me :( I tried to reach the developer who made the custom site but he has stopped replying so I'm on my own for this one.

Comment: you need to edit the code and add `{% if product.id == 5274677084323 %}your product specfic image{% else %}your current image goes here{% endif %}`

Answer (score 0):

you can conditionally render the accordion with product handle

```
{% if product.handle == 'cumin-lentil-pot-pie-vegetarian'%}
<div class="accordion">
   <h4>Heating Instructions</h4>
   <button class="x">✕</button>
   <p class="answer"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0332/6997/3128/t/15/assets/directions.png?v=63874448465039500411650314323" alt="Directions"></p>
</div>
{% endif %}
```